# When is internal energy proportional to temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

A supervisor of mine claims that the following formula holds
$$
U = \rho V C T,
$$
where $U$ is internal energy, $\rho$ is density, $V$ is volume, $C$ is specific heat capacity and $T$ is temperature. I have tried to find this formula in the literature, but all I can find is the well known equation
$$
dU = \rho V C dT.
$$
I have mentioned this to my supervisor, and he replied that the latter equation can be derived from the first by assuming $(\rho V C)$ to be constant, for then $dU = d(\rho V C T) = \rho V C dT$ according to him. However, I am a bit alarmed by the fact that I am still unable to find the aforementioned equation for $U$ in any of the literature I have read so far. Could anyone here please settle the debate about whether or not the first equation above is generally valid? Also, if it is not generally valid, I would be interested in knowing if it is valid under any other assumptions than $(\rho V C)$ = constant. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a real gas, even in the ideal gas limit, your original equation never holds.  A real gas has phase transitions in which U changes discontinuously with temperature, and C for a real gas is a function of temperature.  Only for the highly idealized case of an ideal gas that stays ideal all the way down to absolute zero and has a constant heat capacity can you even think about U as being directly proportional to T.

Comment: Thank you @ChetMiller! I would accept this as an answer if you post it as an answer rather than just a comment. In any case, I gave your comment an upvote.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I know that the equation $U=C_VT+U_0$ (one can take $U_0$ as zero) is mentioned and discussed in Callen's and in Kubo's thermodynamics textbooks as one of the two equations of state for an ideal gas. [Many new thermodynamics practitioners become confused](http://john.maloney.org/cruelest_equation.htm) because they see the differential form $dU=C_V\,dT$ or difference form $\Delta U=C_V\Delta T$ and conclude (incorrectly) that it applies only to constant-volume processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a real gas, even in the ideal gas limit, your original equation never holds. A real gas has phase transitions in which U changes discontinuously with temperature, and C for a real gas is a function of temperature. Only for the highly idealized case of an ideal gas that stays ideal all the way down to absolute zero and has a constant heat capacity can you even think about U as being directly proportional to T.

Answer (score 0):

In classical systems, the internal *kinetic* energy is proportional to temperature. And also quadratic terms in the internal potential energy, according to the equipartition principle. This gives the Dulong & Petit law for the heat capacity of solids.

So that sounds general, but it cannot be true at phase transitions. It also breaks down at low temperatures when quantum effects are important, where the heat capacity must go to zero according to the Third law (Nernst's law).